# who can help me with a tutorial of rosbuild for ros electric

Tags: ros, rosbuild, eclipse, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i need a turtorial of rosbuild for ros electric, idon't want change ros version for hydro, fuerte ... i want work in ros electric thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182541/who-can-help-me-with-a-tutorial-of-rosbuild-for-ros-electric/) by [SEBASSALSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4655/sebassalsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-07-02**:
what is your problem? can you clarify where you are stuck and what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tutorials for rosbuild are still there. That should help you solve the issue.
I think every tutorial still has the catkin and rosbuild tabs wherever necessary.

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0